# Angular 2 binding an event to a component at its selector level

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following Angular 2 component:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-button',
  templateUrl: 'button.html'
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  private text: string;
  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer
  ) {
    this.text = 'test';
  }

  touchmove(event) {
    console.log(this)
  }

}
```

I have the button's html

```
{{button}}
```

I have the component where its used in another page:

What I want to do is to bind the `<my-button (touchmove)="touchmove()">`. I can't do this though because the logic for this has to happen inside the component not outside it.

I don't really want to make a sub-element inside the button template. I've tried binding to the element using:

```
this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'touchmove', this.touchmove);
```

The problem with the above strategy is though, when `touchmove` is fired, `this` is null. If I use `this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'touchmove', this.touchmove.bind(this))` also acts a odd because the `event` argument is weird, sometimes it has no touches in it (which doesn't happen when I use a `(touchmove)="touchmove()"` style binding on the component parent's page.

Is there a correct way to bind the events without using a sub element in my button template, or getting the weird binding issues i'm having?

Edit:

By inside my component, I mean if I did this with my html instead of {{button}}

```
<div (touchmove)="touchmove()">{{text}}</div>
```

It solves my issue, but I can't bind to this  i want to bind to the element that contains this div, the component selector itself: `my-button`

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. What is this about " I can't do this though because the logic for this has to happen inside the component not outside it." What is inside? What is outside?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I edited with a bit more clarity. I also tried using bind, but the events are sometimes wrong, like touchmove has nothing in the touches attribute of the event argument. This doesn't happen when I use the code in my edit, the problem is I can't use a sub-element.

Comment: Using arrow functions helped me btw (thanks!), it solved the issue :)

Comment: Weird. I was sure arrow and `.bind(this)` do the same.

Comment: I'm not sure of the reason either, or the reason the touches are empty but not for sub elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use arrow function then `this` will work

```
this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'touchmove', (e) => this.touchmove(e));
```